# Semantic ui - set sidebar property based on if another component is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I have two semantic sidebars, one on the left and one on the right. Currently, when only the left one is toggled, the page is dimmed, however, when the right one is selected, the page is not dimmed. What I'm trying to achieve is that, when I toggle the left sidebar to open AND the right one is already toggled, I want the page to dim.

Code for toggling right sidebar:

```
  getHistory(){
    $('#sidebar1').sidebar({dimPage:false,overlay:true,closable:false}).sidebar('toggle');

    this.historyPane = true;
  }
```

Code for toggling left sidebar:

```
onSubmit(event){
    if(event.key=="Enter"){
    .
    .
    .
    $('#sidebar').sidebar({overlay:false,dimPage:true}).sidebar('toggle');
    }
```

I have tried to check if the left sidebar is visible using the `.is(:visible)` method, however that returns true even when the sidebar is not toggled. Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if another sidebar is opened using this SUI method:

`$('#sidebar1').sidebar("is visible")`

With that in place, you can do something like this

```
onSubmit(event){
if(event.key=="Enter"){

.
.
.

const shouldDimPage = $('#sidebar1').sidebar("is visible")
$('#sidebar').sidebar({overlay:false, dimPage: shouldDimPage}).sidebar('toggle');
}
```

Similarly you can use `$('#sidebar1').sidebar('is hidden')` should the need arrive

Comment: I tried using the `is visible` property to set a boolean variable, however it does not seem to reflect the updated property when the new sidebar is toggled until the existing sidebar is re-toggled

Comment: can you add a jsFiddle with a basic structure and the code you're using?